# Is it possible to run unit tests with wxWidgets with just the console and no UI?

Tags: linux, unit-testing, gtk, wxwidgets

I am trying to run some unit tests for code that makes use of wxWidgets windows. In the process, windows are created, but never displayed. This works fine under Linux where a display is available, but not on build systems that don't have X or any other UI/display.

The error I get is: "Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?"

Is it possible to unit test wxWidgets without a display? I'm hoping there is some way to just have a stub or "null" display that doesn't really exist, but would allow the unit tests to execute.

As mentioned, I don't need to actually display any window, but from the working tests on a system with a UI, I do need to initialize the app, and create a top level window, like so:

```
wxEntryStart(argc, argv);
wxTheApp->OnInit();
wxFrame frame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "Test Frame");
wxTheApp->SetTopWindow(&frame);
```

Comment: what version of the library do you use? The recent versions - 3.1+ - all use TravisCI and AppVeyor. And I believe the library itself does run the unit test suite on them. You can look at how it is done or just ask on the wx-dev ML and someone will be able explain it in further details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) server (or perhaps an Xvnc server), and use it as your dummy display.